# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type character varying

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to execute a query using parameter specified in URL directly in spring boot. 
Ex - http://localhost:8080/users?username=test&city=london&...
In Spring boot I am replacing and forming a PostgreSQL query 
like that

```
private List<Users> findByQuery(String query) {
    return entityManager
           .createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM public.user where ? ", Users.class)
           .setParameter(1, query)
           .getResultList();
}
```

where the query would be something like that

```
SELECT * FROM public.user where username='test' AND City='london'
```

Its basically to implement server-side filters and we have 6 or 7 of them

But I keep getting following error

> 2018-08-29 10:55:45.832  WARN 54751 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42804
>   2018-08-29 10:55:45.833 ERROR 54751 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type character varying
>     Position: 48
>   2018-08-29 10:55:45.849 ERROR 54751 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type character varying
>     Position: 48

Comment: "query" has to be "boolean". And it isn't seemingly.

Comment: @BillyFrost but it works fine when i hardcode .. like .. SELECT * FROM public.user where username='test' .. but it gives me error when .. SELECT * FROM public.user where ?  ..

Comment: Are you sure that you can insert where condition as parameters? setParameter is used when you have to insert dinamically a single value, like: SELECT * ... WHERE NAME = ?'

Comment: @Innet it should be able to accept it .. as where take a string condition to find something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here

```
  final String jpql = "SELECT * FROM user where " + filter;

    return entityManager
            .createNativeQuery(jpql, User.class)
            .getResultList();
```

http://shazsterblog.blogspot.com/2017/01/spring-data-jpa-with-dynamic-where.html

Comment: I would be filtering and making string filter .. so it shouldn't be an issue

Answer (score 0):

You are missing field name in where clause.

Change

```
SELECT * FROM public.user where ?
```

to

```
SELECT * FROM public.user where username = ?
```

Comment: i cannot hardcode field variable name it needs to come from url hence the query needs to be formed dynamically .. like having whatever filter is passed from front end in url and using the url in where clause of course after tidying it up

Comment: as far as I know i don't think dynamic where clause will allow that.

Comment: there should be = (equals) sign after username probably